# Cannot load images through Facebook using Open Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I simply cannot get my image to load. My website runs through `Squarespace` and I have added the following code to the page:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.clairefeldkamp.co.uk/the-yoga-circle" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="The Yoga Circle" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Guidance, support and community for yoga teachers" />
<meta property="og:image:url" content="https://www.clairefeldkamp.co.uk/yoga_circle_fb_banner.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200"/>
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1616247968705415" />
```

The Facebook debugger says:

Inferred Property
The `'og:image'` property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Inferred Property
The `'og:image'` property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Share App ID Missing
The `'fb:app_id'` property should be explicitly provided, Specify the `app ID` so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, `app_id` can be set in url when open the share dialog.

Can anyone help I am at the end of my tether trying to fix it!!!

Comment: Your site does not have a valid SSL certificate. Why are you using HTTPS for the image anyway? If the rest of your site uses HTTP only, then it makes little sense to use HTTPS for the image. And the debug tool can most likely not “see” your tags, because of your invalid HTML: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.clairefeldkamp.co.uk%2Fthe-yoga-circle

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests to add this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.clairefeldkamp.co.uk/yoga_circle_fb_banner.jpg"/>
```

Btw, it seems that the URL is not reachable, make sure it is and make sure you have a valid SSL certificate if you use https.

Also, make sure that the OG tags are accessible without JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, I am just sorting out some DNS and other issues - hopefully this will sort it all out!

Comment: well...the debugger usually tells you what´s wrong.

Comment: i have added another info to my answer. it seems that you are loading the page with javascript, so the facebook scraper will never even get to the og tags. you have to make sure that the og tags are accessible without javascript.